# How to set a static port for Brackets live preview?

Tags: text-editor, adobe-brackets

My application is using localstorage and in order to test and make sure everything is working properly, I wanted to set a specific port for Brackets live preview option, curious as to how this can be done

Saw the following pull request but unsure how to implement it: https://github.com/adobe/brackets/pull/6815

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set base url in file>project settings...
[image]

Comment: ah perfect, thanks a tonne! :-) didn't know that option existed - one thing though, its not starting the localserver but rather asking me to do it, so thinking what the best way to start the server would be? i'm using an Angular app so no backend as such but should i install Nodejs on the same server to enable localhost or can i somehow start bracket's localhost service manually?

Comment: As far as Brackets starts it's own server you don't need to start nodejs server or anything else unless you have some data to fetch from back-end.

Comment: here's what i get when i set it manually in project settings: http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/115817/5ed7fb849af25fe9db6cf4afd7803f67 - its pure frontend so ideally, I'd like to start the brackets server manually, otherwise will just setup Express - feedback would be great :-)